# Abstract Algebra: If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of an abelian group $G$ of order $m$ and $n$, prove $G$ has a subgroup of order $\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H$ a subgroup of order $m$ and $K$ a subgroup of order $n$. Prove that G has a subgroup of order $\mathrm{lcm} (m,n)$     (lcm = least common multiple).

any thoughts? thanks!

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention it was abelian

Comment: The group G, that is

Comment: Can you prove it when $\gcd(m,n)=1$ at least? Do you know the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups?

Answer (score 2):

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, then by Lagrange, $m\mid |G|$ and $n\mid |G|$. Elementary number theory now says $\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)\mid |G|$. Since $G$ is abelian, for each divisor $k$ of its order, it has a subgroup of size $k$. Therefore, there is one of size $\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest counterexample I can think of (and possibly the smallest counterexample there is):

The G be the semidirect product of an elementary abelian group of order $4$ ($V_4$) and a cyclic group of order $3$ ($C_3$) acting on the $V_4$ in a nontrivial matter. Then $G$ has $3$ subgroups of order $2$, $4$ subgroups of order $3$ but no subgroup of order $6$ since each tuple $(a,b) \in G \times G$ with $a$ of order $2$ and $b$ of order $3$ already generates $G$.

Edit: Wrote this answer before the additional information that $G$ is abelian was made. Will leave it here just in case...

Comment: sorry for that :(